# Mysterious span tag causing errors

Tags: css, validation, html

I've started learning to use firebug to identify css problems, but I really have no clue about this one. [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcheapgamessales.com%2Fproduct%2FAGON-The-Lost-Sword-of-Toledo.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) is saying that I should move the `<span>` tags inside the `<div>`:

`Line 205, Column 55: Element div not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`

```
<pre id=line1><span><div class ='pto_product'>
```

The problem is that there's no `span` tag before `div class =pto_product` in the html markup area in the plugin so I suspect there's something to do with the page template.

I've checked the span tags with firebug, and it seems to related to this line in the stylesheet:

```
pre {margin: 20px 0px; padding: 20px; white-space: pre-wrap; 
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; 
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; 
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.85); }
address { letter-spacing: 1px; margin: 20px 0; }
```

I removed the whole line but nothing changed. I took a step further and deleted all the classes and ids in the stylesheet that contain "span" but that `span` is still there. Would anyone please tell me how to get rid of that tag? Any help is much appreciated.

[Image http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/cssproblem_zps53199bb7.png](http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/cssproblem_zps53199bb7.png)

[HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcheapgamessales.com%2Fproduct%2FAGON-The-Lost-Sword-of-Toledo.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

[Page Link](http://cheapgamessales.com/product/AGON-The-Lost-Sword-of-Toledo.html)

Comment: Any chance it's being inserted with JavaScript?

Comment: No, no JavaScript, it is visible in the source code. And we can't help you like this. We can not tell you why it is there. You have to show us some code how the page is build.

Comment: That's not the source code. That's firebug. It displays dynamic HTML also.

Comment: If it's in the source code, remove it. What you're looking at in firebug isn't the source code, it's the rendered DOM. That span is being inserted by something outside your markup source code. And it's not the CSS. CSS acts on elements, it doesn't create them.

Comment: Why are you editing your style sheet to remove a span tag? Styles can't add html markup

Comment: Yea the css you have has nothing to do with the span tag being created. Span must of been inserted dynamically from JS or whatever templating system you got

Comment: And yes, you do have that span in your template. Open the .html with a text editor and search for "line1". The span is the one right after it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I've checked the page template but after removing all the span tags it's still there. I guess it has something to do with the tablesorter or the plugins I'm using. I'll get back to you later.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can use this.

```
$("#line1").find("span").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Check your code. I'm sure you use span or it generated with some java script code. I use firebug for a while years and never see something like this expect when I use mistake plugins or mistake server side generation. Also you can see page source.